# Save photos from the camera (NOT FROM THE LIBRARY) to the server

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, applescript

I have a question about how to save just taken photo to the server.

I already created a View with the camera (you can open it and take a picture and saved it to your camera roll) and the second View (where you can upload images from the camera roll to the server)

But how I can connect them?

My code

**Choose photo from the libruary**:

**PictureView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct PictureView: View {
    
    // show image picker
    @State var showImagePicker: Bool = false
    
    // show selected image
    @State var selectedImage: Image? = Image("")
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // create button to select image
            Button(action: {
                self.showImagePicker.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("Select image")
            })
            
            // show image
            self.selectedImage?.resizable().scaledToFit()
            
            // show button to upload image
            Button(action: {
                // convert image into base 64
                
                let uiImage: UIImage = self.selectedImage.asUIImage()
                let imageData: Data = uiImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) ?? Data()
                let imageStr: String = imageData.base64EncodedString()
                
                // send request to server
                guard let url: URL = URL(string:
                     "gs://lalala-af09c.appspot.com/swiftui-save-image.php") else {
                    print("invalid URL")
                    return
                }
                
                // create parameters
                let paramStr: String = "image=\(imageStr)"
                let paramData: Data = paramStr.data(using: .utf8) ?? Data()
                
                var urlRequest: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
                urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
                urlRequest.httpBody = paramData
                
                // required for sending large data
                urlRequest.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                
                // send the request
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                    guard let data = data else {
                        print("invalid data")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    // show response in string
                    let responseStr: String = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
                    print(responseStr)
                })
                .resume()
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Upload image")
            })
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker, content: {
            ImagePicker(image: self.$selectedImage)
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PictureView()
    }
}
```

**ImagePicker**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

extension View {
    public func asUIImage() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        
        controller.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: CGFloat(Int.max), width: 1, height: 1)
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(controller.view)
        
        let size = controller.sizeThatFits(in: UIScreen.main.bounds.size)
        controller.view.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        controller.view.sizeToFit()
        
        // here is the call to the function that converts UIView to UIImage: `.asImage()`
        let image = controller.view.asUIImage()
        controller.view.removeFromSuperview()
        return image
    }
}

extension UIView {
// This is the function to convert UIView to UIImage
    public func asUIImage() -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
            layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
    }
}

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode)
    var presentationMode

    @Binding var image: Image?

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

        @Binding var presentationMode: PresentationMode
        @Binding var image: Image?

        init(presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>, image: Binding<Image?>) {
            _presentationMode = presentationMode
            _image = image
        }

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                                   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            let uiImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
            image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
            presentationMode.dismiss()

        }

        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            presentationMode.dismiss()
        }

    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(presentationMode: presentationMode, image: $image)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController,
                                context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {

    }

}
```

And solution to open camera is:
CameraView

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
struct CameraView: View {
    @StateObject var camera = CameraModel()
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
    //    Color.black
            CameraPreview(camera: camera)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack{
                
                if camera.isTaken{
                    HStack{
                    Spacer()
                        Button(action: camera.reTake, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.triangle.2.circlepath.camera")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            
                    }).padding(.trailing,10)
                }
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
                HStack{
                    if camera.isTaken{
                        Button(action: {
                            if !camera.isSaved{
                                camera.savePic()
                            }
                        }, label: {
                            Text(camera.isSaved ? "Saved" : "Save")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                .padding(.vertical,10)
                                .padding(.horizontal,20)
                                .background(Color.white)
                                .clipShape(Capsule())
                        }).padding(.leading)
                        Spacer()
                        
                    }else{
                        Button(action: camera.takePic, label: {
                            ZStack{
                                Circle()
                                    .fill(Color.white)
                                    .frame(width: 65, height: 65, alignment: .center)
                                Circle()
                                    .stroke(Color.white,lineWidth: 2)
                                    .frame(width: 75, height: 75, alignment: .center)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }.frame(height: 75)
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: {
            camera.check()
        }).alert(isPresented: $camera.alert){
            Alert(title: Text("Enable camera"))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CameraView()
    }
}


class CameraModel : NSObject, ObservableObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate{
    @Published var isTaken = false
    @Published var session = AVCaptureSession()
    @Published var alert = false
    @Published var output = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    
    @Published var preview : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    
    @Published var isSaved=false
    @Published var picData = Data(count:0)
    func check(){
        
        switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
        case .authorized:
            setUp()
            return
        case .notDetermined :
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { (status) in
                if status{
                    self.setUp()
                }
            }
        case .denied:
            self.alert.toggle()
            return
            
        default:
            return
        }
    }
    
    func setUp(){
        do{
            self.session.beginConfiguration()
         
            guard let device: AVCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera,
                for: .video, position: .back) else {
                return
            }
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
            if self.session.canAddInput(input){
                print("input taken")
                self.session.addInput(input)
            }else{
                print("input not  taken")
            }
            if self.session.canAddOutput(output){
                print("output taken")
                self.session.addOutput(output)
            }
            self.session.commitConfiguration()
        }catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func takePic(){
         self.output.capturePhoto(with: AVCapturePhotoSettings(), delegate: self)
         DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
             self.session.stopRunning()
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 withAnimation{
                     self.isTaken.toggle()
 
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 
     func reTake(){
 
         DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
             self.session.startRunning()
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 withAnimation{
                     self.isTaken.toggle()
 
                 }
                     self.isSaved=false
                     self.picData=Data(count: 0)
 
             }
         }
     }
 
     func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
         if error != nil{
             return
         }
         print("picture taken")
         guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else {
             return
         }
         self.picData = imageData
     }
 
     func savePic(){
         guard let image = UIImage(data: self.picData) else{return}
         //saving image
         UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
         self.isSaved=true
         print("pic saved")
     }
 
}

struct CameraPreview : UIViewRepresentable{
    @ObservedObject var camera : CameraModel
    func makeUIView(context:Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView(frame:UIScreen.main.bounds)
        camera .preview = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: camera.session)
        camera.preview.frame = view.frame
        camera.preview.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(camera.preview)
        self.camera.session.startRunning()
        return view
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: [maybe](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-take-a-photo-using-the-camera-and-uiimagepickercontroller); [maybe](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-open-the-camera-and-photo-library-in-swiftui-9693f9d4586b); [maybe](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-pick-an-image-from-camera-or-photo-library-in-swiftui-a596a0a2ece); [maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58250976/i-need-to-be-able-to-open-the-camera-in-swiftui-and-take-a-photo-in-an-app)

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes,i know how to open camera,but how after taking a picture upload it to the server?

I didn't find anything about it

Only how to upload photos to the server from the camera roll...

Comment: The very first link shows you how to get the photo from the camera (when a picture is taken), the others are related to SwiftUI.  From there, it's just a matter of using your upload workflow to upload the image returned to you

Answer (score 0):

to upload image..

1. get image from Camera
2. Api to accept image
3. Use URLSession to upload image to server.

   3.1 Use Alamofire to upload image, which is more simpler way to upload
   image